Implement stack using two queues: failing test case
I implemented the push and pop functions -- based on two queues -- below:
from queue import Queue

def push(x):
    # global declaration
    global queue_1
    global queue_2

    # code here
    if queue_1.empty() and queue_2.empty():
        queue_1.put(x)
    if queue_1.empty()==1 and queue_2.empty()==0:
        queue_1.put(x)
        while queue_2.empty()==0:
            y=queue_2.get()
            queue_1.put(y)
    if queue_1.empty()==0 and queue_2.empty()==1:
        queue_2.put(x)
        while queue_1.empty()==0:
            y=queue_1.get()
            queue_2.put(y)

# Function to pop an element from stack using two queues.
def pop():
    # global declaration
    global queue_1
    global queue_2

    # code here
    if queue_1.empty() and queue_2.empty():
        return -1
    if queue_1.empty()==1:
        x=queue_2.get()
    else:
        x=queue_1.get()
    return x

I tried using the concept that at one point one queue will be empty and we will add the new element in that empty queue and get all the elements from the other queue and append them to the queue that has the newly added element. That way, when we pop a element, we will get the more recently added elements first.
Still the above code fails for some simple test cases, like this:
queue_1 = Queue()
queue_2 = Queue()
push(1)
push(2)
assert pop() == 2
assert pop() == 1   # Assertion failed

Where is my mistake?

Not sure what you're really trying to achieve but your code is more complex than it needs to be to get the desired effect.
Looks like you're trying to implement a LIFO queue. You may not need queues for this. Consider using a deque.
You can simplify it like this and your assertions will be True:
from queue import Queue

def pop(q1: Queue, q2: Queue)-> int:
    if q1.empty():
        if q2.empty():
            return -1
        return q2.get()
    return q1.get()

def push(x: int, q1: Queue, q2: Queue):
    if q1.empty():
        q1.put(x)
        while not q2.empty():
            q1.put(q2.get())
    else:
        q2.put(x)
    
def main():
    q1 = Queue()
    q2 = Queue()
    push(1, q1, q2)
    push(2, q1, q2)
    assert pop(q1, q2) == 2
    assert pop(q1, q2) == 1


To use two queues to implement a stack, the convention is to only perform the push and pop operations on a single queue. The second queue is used for the internal implementation. This simplifies the logic required for the operations and avoids the spaghetti condition checks that are present in your push() implementation.
from collections import deque

queue_1 = deque()
queue_2 = deque()

def push(x):
    global queue_1
    queue_1.append(x)


def pop():
    global queue_1
    global queue_2

    if not queue_1:
        return None  # Stack is empty

    # Move all elements from queue_1 to queue_2 except the last one
    while len(queue_1) > 1:
        queue_2.append(queue_1.popleft())

    # The last element in queue_1 is the one to be removed (pop operation)
    popped_value = queue_1.popleft()

    # Swap queue_1 and queue_2 (queue_2 becomes queue_1 for next operations)
    queue_1, queue_2 = queue_2, queue_1

    return popped_value


def top():
    global queue_1
    global queue_2

    if not queue_1:
        return None  # Stack is empty

    # Move all elements from queue_1 to queue_2 except the last one
    while len(queue_1) > 1:
        queue_2.append(queue_1.popleft())

    # The last element in queue_1 is the top element of the stack
    top_value = queue_1[0]

    # Move the last element back to queue_1
    queue_2.append(queue_1.popleft())

    # Swap queue_1 and queue_2 (queue_2 becomes queue_1 for next operations)
    queue_1, queue_2 = queue_2, queue_1

    return top_value


def empty():
    global queue_1
    return len(queue_1) == 0


This is a fine answer, but you say "To use two queues to implement a stack, the convention is...", and I think it's worth pointing out that 2 queues are never used to implement a stack except in school exercises, because the pop is very inefficient, and stacks are simpler than queues to begin with.
